# How do I display the next sentence of a text file after the user presses enter in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a text file that I am printing line by line with the bash commands:

```
while read -r line;
do
    echo "$line"
done < file.txt
```

I want the command line to wait for the user to press return between each line being printed. I read that this functionality is offered by:

```
read -p "Press enter:"
```

But when I add this in, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line;
do
   echo "$line" ;
   read -p "Press enter:";
done < file.txt
```

it does not change the result of the script from the first version. How can I obtain this functionality?

Comment: `read -p "Press enter:" </dev/tty`?

Comment: @JohnSmith : `read -p XXX` reads the next line from stdin (i.e. in your case from `file.txt`) and stores this line into the variable `REPLY`; you can verify this behaviour by adding a `echo REPLY="$REPLY"` after the `read -p`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a different file descriptor for file, while different for stdin:

```
while IFS= read -u 3 -r line;
do
   echo "$line" ;
   read -p "Press enter:";
done 3<file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Or simply use more with argument `-1`...

```
more -1 file.txt
```

...with the possibilities to `q`uit or do a search with `/searchstring` some `h`elp and of course to see next line with ENTER.